# How to limit bandwith connection on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bandwidth

On my local network, there are several computers running Ubuntu. The users of this network have the habits to download a large amount of big files everyday, however our Internet connection is quite slow.

As the network manager, I would like to know if it was possible to limit the maximum bandwidth of each computer to share equal internet connection on each computer...

My computers are running Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server that all traffic goes through, but QoS will do it.  You will need to read up on it to figure it out, and it has numerous settings and options.

Also a proxy server will cache downloads so after one person downloads a file the next user gets it from the proxy cache there by saving bandwidth. Squid is quite popular.